# "Accept-Language" header sent by Chrome browser on Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

What exactly it depends upon?

For example, if I have only one language specified in the Settings, but the `Accept-Language` header appears as:

> uk-UA,uk;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6,en-US;q=0.4,en;q=0.2

How can I remove extra languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I tested, the following behaviours apply to both Android and Linux Desktop versions of Google Chrome:

Every time you change your system locale (via `LANG` environment variable on Linux; or via System - Languages settings on Android), Google Chrome resets its own language settings (and the `Accept-Language` header) to a pre-defined list.

For example, if you set system locale to "English (Canada) / en_CA.UTF-8" and restart Chrome, the `Accept-Language` header will contain four locales: en_CA, en_GB, en_US, and en.

In Chrome settings, you can adjust the list of languages, leaving only "English" (no region suffix), and after a restart of Chrome, the `Accept-Language` header will contain only one locale: en.

I do not know about uk / ru languages, but you could try adjusting the language list in Chrome settings (don't forget to restart Chrome) and visit https://httpbin.org/headers to examine your `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: It's strange, but now the languages in the settings and the languages in the `Accept-Language` header do really correspond. Probably that was a problem related to specific version of Google Chrome (or specific environment, at that time I used "Fly" phone, which I abandoned later). Anyway, thanks for you answer.